# T-SQL trigger effect a change before calling other code

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have a table, let's call is *[MYTABLE]*, with an *FOR INSERT, UPDATE* trigger.

The trigger needs to execute a stored procedure, which will do some work based on the changes made to *[MYTABLE]*. I can't move the stored procedure's code into the trigger.

So far, so good... since triggers execute *after* the changes are made, the stored procedure has no need to access the *[inserted]* or *[deleted]* metatables.

However... the trigger needs to change *one additional field* (a *[LastModified]* smalldatetime) so the stored procedure can use that data in its processing. This is *not* so the stored procedure can see what was inserted/updated... the procedure may do a number of things based on other records that weren't included in the update triggering it.

Problem is, if my trigger changes *[LastModified]*, that will either do *nothing at all* (if I have recursive triggers turned off), or it will end up calling the stored procedure twice--once because of the original triggering change, and again because of my change to *[LastModified]*.

How can I get around this so (a) *[LastModified]* gets updated with each change and (b) the stored procedure is only called after *it* has access to the new value of *[LastModified]*?

I have two ideas I'm thinking about, but they smell funny, so I'd rather see if there's a more straightforward solution.

**Edit:**

Ok, here are the solutions I have so far, maybe that will help the discussion:

**1. Use two triggers.** One, an "INSTEAD OF" trigger, would handle the user's update of the record and would change LastModified, but would RETURN quickly if the update is coming *from* the SP (it can tell based on what columns are modified). The other would be an "AFTER" trigger, which would call the EXEC. This trigger gets the updates with the LastModified column *already applied* by the INSTEAD OF trigger. At least I hope that's how it works.

**2. Move ModifiedDate to another table.** That way, I can have a single AFTER INSERT/UPDATE trigger that, *only* if the user initiates the INSERT/UPDATE, adds an audit record to the other table and calls the SP. The SP would then modify other records, which would cause the trigger to fire again, but it would quickly recognize the situation and RETURN without doing more work.

The disadvantage of the first solution is that I have to maintain a column list in the trigger so the INSTEAD OF update actually does the work intended (since I'm adding a column to the list, ModifiedDate, I can't just INSERT INTO tbl FROM inserted, I have to specify columns).

Comment: How is the initial INSERT/UPDATE being performed?  And do you have to use a trigger?  Reason I ask is that the entire course of events could be encapsulated within a stored procedure (without the need for a trigger at all).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the IF UPDATE(LastModified) instruction?

```
CREATE TRIGGER XYZ ON MYTABLE 
FOR INSERT, UPDATE 
AS 
BEGIN 
IF UPDATE(LastModified) 
  RETURN 
ELSE 
  BEGIN
    UPDATE MYTABLE SET LastModified = GETDATE() 
    FROM MYTABLE INNER JOIN INSERTED ON MYTABLE.ID = INSERTED.ID
    EXEC TheStoreProc
  END
END;
```

Comment: This solves the problem of the EXEC being called on the wrong side of the workflow, but doesn't actually change LastModified, which needs to be updated *by* the trigger.

Comment: Fixed the script, now update the table and THEN execute the script. The trigger will be "triggered" twice, but the inner execution will end immediately.

Comment: Rodrigo-- thanks, but if this is done, will the EXEC "see" th LastModified changed? It makes sense that it would see it, unless triggers work within an implied transaction of some sort.

Comment: This one is close enough to what I ended up doing, so I'm accepting it as the correct answer. Only difference for me was that INSERT *will* return TRUE for UPDATE(LastModified), and I need those calls to skip the unnecessary UPDATE on LastModified (since it was already set by a default on insert), but it should call the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the flow you are describing.  Is it:

1. Record is updated
2. Update trigger proc is called
3. trigger updates LastModified field
4. trigger calls another proc

that should work fine, as long as the "another proc" does not update the same table,
which would kick off the trigger again.

If the "another proc" **is** updating the table again, you could possibly move those updates
into the trigger prior to calling "another proc".

Is that any help?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's exactly what is happening. The SP will *never* update the *same* records as the "original" trigger, but it will update others, which will call the trigger again. So, while there's no chance of recursion, it's still a messy little one-step loop. And, unfortunately, moving the SP code into the trigger does no good (since the SP only affects *other* records, an INSTEAD OF trigger won't reduce the one-step recursion) and would make the code less maintainable (triggers on several tables call the same SP). I'd rather use a view, but don't get to make the call this time.